# I'm trying insert values into MySQL database, getting NullPointerException

Tags: java, mysql, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to insert some data captured by a gui form into my database. When I run the program, and try to add a vendor, I'm getting a nullpointerexception, and am having trouble figuring out why. Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Java Method:

```
private void addVendorToDbButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                    

         addVendorPanel.setVisible(true);

         //ANDY:
         String vendorName = addVendorNameField.getText();
         String customerName = addCustomerNumField.getText();
         String vendorCode = addVendorCodeField1.getText();

     String sql = "INSERT INTO VENDORS (Vendor,Cust#,Vendorcode)"+"VALUES('"+vendorName+"','"+customerName+"','"+vendorCode+"')";
     try {
         openconnection();
         rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
     } catch (SQLException ex) {
         Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
     }
}
```

OpenConnection:

```
public void openconnection(){
     Connection conn = null;
        try {
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://sql3.freemysqlhosting.net:3306/sql376856", "xxxx","xxxxx");
      System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    try {
        Statement statement = conn.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Declare Global Variables for Use:

```
public class gui extends javax.swing.JFrame {


 Statement statement;  
 Connection conn;
 ResultSet rs;
/**
 * Creates new form gui
 */
public gui() {
    initComponents();
}
```

Error Message:

```
run:
Connected database successfully...
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at database.gui.addVendorToDbButtonActionPerformed(gui.java:1142)
at database.gui.access$1300(gui.java:23)
at database.gui$14.actionPerformed(gui.java:562)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at        javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6527)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6292)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4883)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4705)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: What is 1142nd line of gui.java?

Comment: rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);

Comment: have you created objects, for addVendorPanel, addVendorNameField, addCustomerNumField or addVendorCodeField or statement? ?

Comment: Did you check whether `statement` is `null`?

Comment: Statement and connection is not instantiated in your local method

Comment: @shinjw I think so? I edited my question to show where I open the connection instantiate the variables

Comment: I believe you need `executeUpdate(sql)` instead of `executeQuery(sql)`.

Comment: @shinjw how would I do that?

Comment: Debug the method addVendorToDbButtonActionPerformed() or do System.out.println(sql); Check the value of the sql. Also check the three objects  addVendorNameField, addCustomerNumField & addVendorCodeField1; Something in this method is null;

Comment: @underdog just checked - sql has the intended string value

Comment: But the JVM throws the NPE on the same line; Debug the code you will find out the solution to this;

Comment: @underdog I believe it is statement - it has to be. Do I need to pass it back from openconnection() into the addVendorToDbButtonActionPerformed? so - statement = openconnection(); after changing return type of openconnection()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your statement variable in the method addVendorToDbButtonActionPerformed is null and hence the nullpointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void openconnection(){
        try {
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://sql3.freemysqlhosting.net:3306/sql376856", "xxxx","xxxxx");
      System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    try {
        statement = conn.createStatement();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(gui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

if you go this route. make sure you make another method to close your connection.

I'd also recommend moving `statement = conn.createStatement();` to the method where you defined your query. Make sure you close the statement and result set in that method after retrieving your results.

Comment: Is there another way to create a connection the entire time the program is running? Instead of just on button click

Comment: @user2977729 Cache the result of the connection, so when you ask for the connection again, return the one you have already opened (by checking to see if the value is `null` or not)

Comment: Look up "JDBC Connection Pooling"

Comment: @shinjw I tried changing the return type of openconnection() to statement, and changing it to statement = openconnection();  in the method. Getting the same error.... should I handle this a different way?

Comment: post your new method. are you returning `conn.createStatement()` in that method?